# Blocked bots from websites using JavaScripting

Tags: javascript

I have made a website that has some information that people are desperate to get, but the amount of data is extremely high which prevent  people to manually copy/past the data. But what I'm worried about is web scrapers such as selenium, I've realised websites like YouTube automatically detect if the user/client is a bot or a real human. There is two ways this could eventually be done, A: use reCAPTCHA, B: write a JavaScript code to detect it automatically.

Option A would have worked perfectly but my website does not require the user to log in to see the information which makes reCAPTCHA useless. In my opinion option B has a lot more potentials because i have experience working with selenium and in my knowledge when u open a selenium screen you will get a text like this [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y19qw.png) which gives me a bit of hope to find it out using JavaScript. Can anyone help me?

Comment: All methods of detecting bots can be bypassed, even the best captchas cost only a few cents to solve.

Comment: How do you host your website? What technologies do you use? Is it your own custom VPS, or you're using a managed service? Perhaps you could put Cloudflare in front of your website. It has a lot of defenses you could use.

Comment: @mousetail True, but there has to be a most secure way right. Otherwise no websites would ever have privacy.

Comment: No websites ever have privacy from scrapping.

Comment: @dodov I apologies but I have not  been informed many things about the server and the technologies we use because I'm only in charge of the code. Though do know we do not use many advanced technologies.

Comment: @mousetail How does YouTube do it?

Comment: If you want to publish this information, you have to make it easily accessible. If it's accessible, scrapers will be able to access it. It sounds counter-intuitive, but honestly, making your site the easiest way to access the data is a good way to discourage "piracy" (Why read somewhere else if your site is the best source for the info anyway?)

Comment: Youtube can be scrapped easily, there are many websites and services that do it. Most famously youtube-dl

Comment: @DBS The websites goal is to inform people for the price and many other information of some items, but we don't want other websites stealing the information we worked hard to gather. In general out goal is to inform people

Comment: @mousetail YouTube can indeed be scraped but when you try to make a YouTube channel or post a video it will not let you.

Comment: This too can be bypassed easily. There are companies that create hundreds of you-tube channels with copied content for scamming purposes.